# CSS stylesheet for website app fullscreen and not fullscreen

Tags: html, css, ipad, safari, media-queries

I'm building a website, which will be used on an iPad. The problem is, that I need to have 2 stylesheets:

One for when the user will see in fullscreen mode (without the address bar) and one for when the site opens standard in Safari.

Is it possible to make a line like:

```
@media only screen and (min-device-width: 481px) and (max-device-width: 1024px) and (orientation:portrait) {}
```

but when it is in fullscreen contra not?

Comment: By fullscreen mode, do you mean Safari's new fullscreen mode in iOS 6, or do you mean when your site is opened as a web app from a Web Clip icon?

Comment: Not the new fullscreen mode, but the other. When someome adds it to homescreen

Comment: Opera uses projection for its "presentation mode", perhaps Safari followed?  http://cssmediaqueries.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In iOS 5 you should be able to target the size of the screen without the menu bar (which takes up exactly `18px`), this way you'll know it's fullscreen, because it should be larger since the menu bar won't be there:

```
@media only screen and  (min-device-width: 672px) and (max-device-width: 1024px) and (orientation:portrait) {}
```

I'm not 100% if that'll work, but I know the black bar at the top takes up `18px`. And the dimensions would be as such:

```
landscape:1024x672 
portrait: 768x928
```

---

**Update**

I've found out how we can do this with jQuery, it relies on `window.navigator.standalone`

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  if (("standalone" in window.navigator) && !window.navigator.standalone) {
    $('head').append("<link href='fullscreen.css' type='text/css' rel='stylesheet' />")
  }
});
```

Now this assumes that mobile safari supports `window.navigator.standalone` and it should. Give it a try.

Comment: Tried different widths for the portrait, but no luck. But from what I can tell, the device width will not change, if the website is set to homescreen or not.

The browser height changes in viewport, but can't seem to target that either :(

Comment: Yes, I just tried it also, it seems you're right, I've found another solution, please look at my updated answer.

Answer (score 1):

the media query you mentioned, works according to the screen width, that's the `device screen dimensions (width)`, without taking into account whether its Safari or fullscreen(like u described w/o address bar). hope it makes sense.

I did a quick search, and found [link](http://menacingcloud.com/?c=iPhoneAddressBar). Hope it helps.

Comment: may i ask u, why you would need to have it handle the 2 cases u mentioned in your question? wouldn't just making it work for device width suffice both?

Comment: The design I'm building has an thumbnail section at the bottom of the site. The site height is 2048px, but when the site is viewed with the addressbar, the thumbnail section almost disappears, but is perfect in homescreen mode. Hope this makes sense.

Comment: yes it does. isnt the max-width(or height) of ipad `1024px`, then why the 2048px?

Comment: aaahhh I'm targting the res., not the width. Thx :) I'll see if that helps